# Sum only the previous two values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a list like [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4] and I wanted to sum the values like:

```
[6, 9, 8, 6, 7, 4]
```

where the formula is `value + value_one_ahead + value_two_ahead`.

Comment: Look at `np.cumsum`.

Comment: The last element of the target is 9, right?

Comment: `np.add.reduceat` can also be used, though setting up the index parameter takes some effort.

Comment: Should the desired output be `[6, 9, 8, 7, 6, 9, 7, 4]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation can be interpreted as a [(discrete) convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution) of the input with [1, 1, 1], so you can use [`numpy.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html):

```
In [178]: x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [179]: np.convolve(x, np.ones(3, dtype=x.dtype), mode='valid')
Out[179]: array([6, 9, 8, 7, 6, 9])
```

See the docstring for the description of the `mode` argument.  You might have to tweak the return value or add a line or two of additional code if the available `mode` options don't handle the ends of the input the way you want.  For example, to get something closer to what you wrote in the question, you can use `mode='full'` (which is the default), and then discard the first two elements (by taking the slice `[2:]`):

```
In [181]: np.convolve(x, np.ones(3, dtype=x.dtype), mode='full')[2:]
Out[181]: array([6, 9, 8, 7, 6, 9, 7, 4])
```

---

Note: `np` was defined using `import numpy as np`.  `np.ones(3, dtype=x.dtype)` creates an array of 1s with the given length and data type:

```
In [180]: np.ones(3, dtype=x.dtype)
Out[180]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
result = []
for i in range(len(l)-2):
    result.append(
        l[i] + l[i+1] + l[i+2]
    )
print result
```

Comment: there's nothing built into numpy?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that's numpy only:

```
>>> arr[:-2] + arr[1:-1] + arr[2:]
array([6, 9, 8, 7, 6, 9])
```